# Android: CMake not building object files and libraries

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

I am working on an android project using native `C++` libraries. I am using `CMake` to build libraries.
Here is a fragment of my `build.gradle` file :

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                        "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=4",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
                        "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21",
                        "-DSHARED_LIBRARY=1",
                        "-DOFFLINE_SYNC_SUPPORT_ENABLED=1",
                        "-DPRE_RC_ONLY=0"

                cFlags "-Werror=return-type", "-Wno-pragmas", "-DBOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE",
                        "-DBOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION",
                        "-DJPEG_DISABLE_OPTIM -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=32",
                        "-mno-unaligned-access",
                        "-Wno-extern-c-compat"
                cppFlags "-Wno-conversion-null", "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-std=c++14", "-DES_ENABLE_LOGGING"
            }
        }


externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('jni/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.18.1'
        }

    }
```

When building, I can see output of `message()` command in `CMake` files in output terminal but it is not compiling my source files and not building libraries. Also I am not getting any error while building.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: The fragment isn't enough. We need to see the CMakeLists.txt.